# Set Python class variable equal to the output of class function

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

Is it possible to set a variable equal to the value that a function returns? In the example below I would want `foo.baz` to be equivalent to calling `foo._baz()`. Wondering if it's possible to have `baz` update without writing code that updates `baz` every time `bar` is updated, while still calling `baz` as an object.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = [1,2,3]
        self.baz = self._baz()
    def _baz(self):
        return max(self.bar)


foo = Foo()

foo.bar
Out[90]: [1, 2, 3]

foo.baz
Out[91]: 3

foo.bar.append(7)

foo.baz
Out[93]: 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make `baz` a  [`property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = [1,2,3]

    @property
    def baz(self):
        return max(self.bar)
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.bar
[1, 2, 3]
>>> foo.baz  # foo.baz is called and returns max(foo.bar)
3
>>> foo.bar.append(7)  # foo.baz is not called
>>> foo.baz  # foo.baz is called and returns max(foo.bar)
7
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.bar = [1,2,3]
...         #self.baz = self._baz()
...     def _baz(self):
...         return max(self.bar)
...     baz = property(_baz)
...
>>>
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.bar
[1, 2, 3]
>>> foo.baz
3
>>> foo.bar.append(7)
>>> foo.baz
7
```

In the above code, `_baz` method is called and the return value of the method is returned when you access the `baz` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why what you have does not work, is because the baz class attribute is only being written to with the max() function only when the object is initialzed - '3' is stored as the value, and never rewritten.

You can further fix by treating the baz attribute as a property - and returning the max() of bar - no writing to attributes, and, of course, will change when the bar attribute is written to.